# Way to support <span> tag in TextView

Tags: android, html, textview

I want to `highlight` some part of my text that will be shown in `TextView`. I know that we can use `SpannableString` in Android to highlight some part of my text. But I want to know, how can we use `<span>` html tag to do same thing. I tried to reach this, using code as following :

```
String str = "<span style=\"background-color:#ffff00\"> Highlighted </span> Text";
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(str));
```

But shown text is the same text without span tag.

What is wrong ? How can I do same thing without using `SpannableString` ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What is wrong ?

`Html.fromHtml()` is limited in terms of what tags it supports. [Here is a blog post](http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html) from a couple of years ago showing the roster of tags `fromHtml()` supported then. Even in [the current code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/text/Html.java) (as of the time of this writing), nothing generates the `BackgroundColorSpan` that you are seeking.

There is nothing stopping somebody from creating a richer HTML->`Spanned` converter that could handle such `<span>` tags, though I am not aware of any existing at the present time.

Hence, at the moment, you will be stuck applying a `BackgroundColorSpan` yourself. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/RichText/Search) where I use `BackgroundColorSpan` to highlight the results of searching a string for particular sub-strings.