# Set Span style HTML text in Text View android

Tags: android, html, string, textview

As I am getting the html text from the service and I need to display the text on text View.

```
Managing Safely <b> End Of Course Theory Test </b> <span style="color:red;"> part1 </span>
```

I am setting this text like

```
tv.settext(Html.fromHTML("Managing Safely <b> End Of Course Theory Test </b> <span style="color:red;"> part1 </span>"));
```

It is showing bold but not showing the color red text.

Comment: Might be a problem with your quotes. Try using single quotes inside your .fromHTML('...'); method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392163/using-multiple-text-colors-in-androids-textview-html-fromhtml

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @ρяσѕρєя K told above that `HTML` span tag is not supported by `Html.fromHtml.`

You should either change the service
OR
add a following line to your code, it will change the span color html to font tags, atleast in your case.

```
String yourHtmlText = yourHtmlText.replace("span style=\"color:", "font color='").replace(";\"","'").replace("</span>", "</font>");
```

For others I'll recommend to use `String.split` frequently according to your needs and it will work like magic.

I hope this works.
Cheers :)

Answer (score 4):

As you can see  [HTML Tags Supported By TextView](http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html)  HTML `span` tag is not supported by  `Html.fromHtml`.

So you should return only supported tags from server like `font,div,p,...` or use webview to show all html tags

Answer (score 2):

you have to use following code to show data from html

```
tv.settext(Html.fromHTML("Managing Safely <b> End Of Course Theory Test </b> <font color='red'>simple</font>"));
```

Comment: the string I am getting from the service All I have to do is to display the text.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12285515/way-to-support-span-tag-in-textview span is not support in android either you have to ask the server end developer to send font tag or you have to change the span to font in your end

Answer (score 1):

enter text seperately

```
TextView text = ... // find or instantinate your text view.
text.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#ff0000'>text</font>"));
```

or use spannable string

```
text.setText("");
text.append("Add all your funky text in here");
Spannable sText = (Spannable) text.getText();
sText.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 1, 4, 0);
```

use this library support all html tags.

https://github.com/NightWhistler/HtmlSpanner

Comment: Please read my question.. I just wanted to display the text which I am getting from the server.